# Is it possible to change github pull request title when merging the PR

Tags: github, pull-request, targetprocess

We have just moved across to Targetprocess.  It looked like it had good github integration, when a commit to that branch has "id:[storyid]" in the title it will detect it and setup the reference.

The issue we have is that we all use forks and create pull requests to merge stories / changes back into the main organisations repository.  Github will not allow us to change the title (that I can see) and Targetprocess does not look at the comments section for the id:[storyid].

Is there a way to be able to change github to allow the merge commit to have the id:[userstory] text in the title?

Answer (score 3):

https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/#merging-a-pull-request-using-the-github-web-interface states that GitHub allows to change message while merging PR via browser interface.

The same applies to the command line interface.

Comment: I can't find the information at that link anymore.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Link is still alive for me